# Make a JDialog always on top of parent (JFrame) but user still can interact with parent

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I'm working on building a text editor program like NotePad.
I want to make FindDialog always on top of MainFrame but user still can edit the text at JTextArea in MainFrame as NotePad.

Please help me!!!

I have used method jdialog.setModal(true). It make dialog always on top of parent but user can't edit the text at parent.

Edit: method setAlwaysOnTop() make dialog on top of all windows (include browsers,other programs..) so i can't use it

Comment: [`Window#setAlwaysOnTop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop(boolean))

Comment: setAlwaysOnTop make dialog on top of all windows (include browers,other programs..) so i can't use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have detected that we can use super(parent) to achieve this.

```
class MyDialog extends JDialog {

    public MyDialog(JFrame parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    /* Other codes */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various modality types (can be) supported. Use `JDialog.setModalityType` method and choose the relevant modality type. For more information check out the javadoc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType)

BTW, calling `setModal(true)` is equivalent to `setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS)`. In this case user can edit the parent.

So you can try either:

```
setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL)
```

or as you creating your JDialog pass the modality

```
new JDialog(parent, "Title", Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
```

There is also this useful tutorial about the modality from Oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html

Notice that there is a slight difference between Document and Application modal.
Choose the appropriate one for your case.

Comment: i have try your suggest but the result is the same with using setModal(true)

Comment: My suggestion was basically using setting a modality type either by a setter or passing through the JDialog's constructor. Not using setModal.